# Meaning of & in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to joomla and trying to figure out the flow of things. I came accross to a call which had `$db =& JFactory::getDBO();`.  What is the meaning of `&` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an assignment(By refrence) operator in PHP, nothing to do with Joomla.

`&` means the variable should be accessed by reference instead of value

For example (From Documentation)

```
<?php
   $a =& $b;
?>
```

So here it means that variables `$a` and `$b` point to the same content.

[**Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: Another good explanation and examples can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#78799) in PHP doc

Answer (score 7):

It's inheritance from Joomla php4 version.

It does not make any sense if you are using PHP version > 5.

Joomla 1.5.x support 4.3.10, where object was copied by value. So, purpose of references was to avoid object copying.